# Running a python script via cmd, len(sys.argv) = 1 independent of how many arguments actually passed

Tags: python, command-line

I am getting some strange behavior on one of my computers.
Consider the simple code:

```
import sys
print len(sys.argv)
```

and lets save this as test.py. Now, under the command line (Windows) typing in "test.py" with result in "1" being printed as expected. However, when I typed in "test.py arg", it still prints out "1". I tried this on another computer with the same Python version installed, and I get the expect "2" printed. Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your file associations are messed up. See what `assoc .py` and `ftype Python.File` have to say. If %* is missing, that would explain it.

```
C:\>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

C:\>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Comment: Thank you
Just did, and I get the exactly what you have.